# How do I prove that for any $2\times2$ matrix $A$, $A^2$ can be written in the linear form $aA + bI$ where $a$ and $b$ are scalars?

Tags: matrices, symmetric-matrices

> How do I prove that for any $2\times2$ matrix $A$, $A^2$ can be written in the linear form $aA + bI$ where $a$ and $b$ are scalars?

I've tried letting the elements of A be $w$, $x$, $y$, and $z$ then finding $A^2$ but I don't know where to go from there. Please help.

Comment: Can you show your workings?

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: See [Cayley-Hamilton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley–Hamilton_theorem).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a well-known theorem (Cayley-Hamilton):

> Suppose that $A$ is an $n \times n$ matrix. Suppose that $f(x) = \det {(xI - A)} = x^n + a_1 x^{n-1} + \dots + a_n$. Then
> $$
> A^n + a_1 A^{n-1} + \dots + a_n I = 0.
> $$

---

Suppose that
$$
A = \begin{bmatrix}
w & x \\
y & z \\
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
I leave the proof of the following identity as your exercise:
$$
A^2 - (w + z) A + (wz - xy) I = 0.
$$
Hence
$$
A^2 = (w + z) A - (wz - xy) I.
$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is there no way to solve the problem without the theorem?

Comment: @HarryTim Your problem is about $2 \times 2$ matrices, so you do not have to mention "Cayley-Hamilton"; you just need to claim that $A^2 = (w + z) A - (wz - xy) I$ and prove it by direct computation. You do not have to explain why the expression occurs to you; you just need to prove that it does work. There are of course other ways to solve your problem, but I think that the easiest method is just the one that I have suggested.

Answer (score 1):

For a $2 × 2$ matrix,
$$
A={\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\ c&d\\ \end{pmatrix}},
$$
the characteristic polynomial is given by $p(λ) = λ^2 − (a + d)λ + (ad − bc)$, so the Cayley–Hamilton theorem states that $P(A)=0$, i.e., that
$$
A^{2}-(a+d)A+(ad-bc)I_{2}={\begin{pmatrix}0&0\\0&0\\\end{pmatrix}}.
$$
The last formula can be verified explicitly, independently of Cayley-Hamilton.